# Error generating proxy with svcutil

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm building a contract-first SOAP client. When I try to generate the proxy classes with svcutil, I get the error messages listed below and no classes are generated. Some of the error messages are in Dutch, but they're similar to the errors in [this question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5969d6a2-a8f7-456a-85dc-a6e3296f7ffc/). The poster of that question provides the following solution:

> [...] WCF Publishing wizard does not like multiple includes (t be precise - more than 3). SO I reduced my Schema includes to zero [...]

Since I'm not in control of the wsdl's and xsd's, and since there are many and they're large, reducing the schema includes would cause severe maintainability problems.
So before I try this, I'd like to know if this is indeed what's causing the problem. I'm unable to find confirmation of this.

Has anybody else heard of this as a cause of problems? Are there other things I could try?

The [wsdl](https://www.surfgroepen.nl/sites/stuf/Shared%20Documents/5_StUF_Sectormodellen/StUF-ZKN0310%20(In%20Ontwikkeling)/zkn0310.beantwoordVraag.wsdl) and [related files](https://www.surfgroepen.nl/sites/stuf/Shared%20Documents/5_StUF_Sectormodellen/StUF-ZKN0310%20(In%20Ontwikkeling)/zkn0310_20100601.zip) are available online.
As far as I can tell they are all valid.

I tried to run svcutil with arguments /dcOnly and /ser:XmlSerializer, but that didn't help. I also tried reducing the set of operations to what I need, but that didn't help either.

Thanks, Miel.

> Error: Er is een validatiefout opgetreden op een schema dat tijdens het exporteren werd gegenereerd:
>   Bron: 
>   Regel: 17518 Kolom: 6
>   Validatiefout: Het attribuut groepsnaam wordt genegeerd omdat de waarde 'prohibited' (verboden) voor attribuutgebruik er alleen voor zorgt dat het overnemen van een identieke attribuutnaam uit de basistypedefinitie wordt verhinderd.
>
> Error: Er is een validatiefout opgetreden op een schema dat tijdens het exporteren werd gegenereerd:
>   Bron: 
>   Regel: 17519 Kolom: 6
>   Validatiefout: Het attribuut elementnaam wordt genegeerd omdat de waarde 'prohibited' (verboden) voor attribuutgebruik er alleen voor zorgt dat het overnemen van een identieke attribuutnaam uit de basistypedefinitie wordt verhinderd.
>
> Error: Kan wsdl:portType niet importeren
>   Detail: Er is een uitzondering opgetreden tijdens het uitvoeren van een WSDL-importextensie: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Fout: Kan geen ongeldige schema's importeren. Compilatie op de XmlSchemaSet is mislukt.
>   XPad naar foutbron: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310']/wsdl:portType[@name='BeantwoordVraag']
>
> Error: Kan wsdl:binding niet importeren
>   Detail: Er is een fout opgetreden bij het importeren van een wsdl:portType waar de wsdl:binding van afhankelijk is.
>   XPad naar wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310']/wsdl:portType[@name='BeantwoordVraag']
>   XPad naar foutbron: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310']/wsdl:binding[@name='SOAPBeantwoordVraag']
>
> Error: Kan wsdl:port niet importeren
>   Detail: Er is een fout opgetreden bij het importeren van een wsdl:binding waar de wsdl:port van afhankelijk is.
>   XPad naar wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310']/wsdl:binding[@name='SOAPBeantwoordVraag']
>   XPad naar foutbron: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310']/wsdl:service[@name='BeantwoordVraag']/wsdl:port[@name='BeantwoordVraag']
>
> Generating files...
>   Warning: No code was generated.
>   If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services
>   or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.
>
> Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody helpful told me that svcutil.exe and wsdl.exe do not handle fault messages defined in a wsdl very well.

After I removed those, svcutil did indeed generate the proxies.

So, at least in this case the problem is not the multiple includes, but fault messages. Now I will need to figure out a workaround for the now missing fault messages.

I'll try to keep this answer updated.